tesseract lost the language pack
C:\Users\xwmsu>tesseract --list-langs
Error opening data file \app\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.

I have set the environment variables in TESSDATA_PREFIX to the corresponding testdata, but he still can't recognize it? Or is the version I installed wrong?
Environment variables, version number, I have tried.
